# Vue: out-in, make the in element appear before the out element has disappeared

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

Codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-architecture-vp4jwn?file=/src/App.vue

I have two `div` elements: `Block 1` and `Block 2`.

When a button is clicked `Block 1` is translated towards the left, until it disappears from view. Then `Block 2` appears from the right side of the parent div.

However `Block 2` doesn't start its movement until `Block 1` has completely disappeared from view.

Is there a way to make `Block 2` appear when `Block 1` is at `50%` of its `translateX` property?

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="show = !show">Click Me!</button>
    <transition mode="out-in">
      <div class="block" id="block-1" v-if="show">Block 1</div>
      <p class="block" id="block-2" v-else>Block 2</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return { show: true };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: 微軟正黑體;
}
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#block-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

#block-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#app {
  padding: 10px;

  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.v-leave-from {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.v-leave-active {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.v-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-220%);
}
.v-enter-from {
  transform: translateX(600%);
}
.v-enter-active {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.v-enter-to {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You try without mode (default mode), then both the old and new elements transition simultaneously:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return { show: true };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 微軟正黑體;
}
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#block-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

#block-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#app {
  padding: 10px;

  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.v-leave-from {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.v-leave-active {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.v-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-220%);
}
.v-enter-from {
  transform: translateX(600%);
}
.v-enter-active {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.v-enter-to {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <button @click="show = !show">Click Me!</button>
    <transition >
      <div class="block" id="block-1" v-if="show">Block 1</div>
      <p class="block" id="block-2" v-else>Block 2</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
```